# Limiting posts based on nested meta_query

Tags: php, database

I have a list of properties that have been created as a custom post type. There are multiple queries that show these posts in different areas of the site.

I'm trying to add the ability to restrict certain posts from appearing for anyone except an approved user, while also keeping pagination, counts, etc, working as expected. I'm trying to modify the queries to achieve this.

To start, I added two new custom fields to the properties. One is to specify whether that post is restricted, which is a 1 or 0 to indicate yes or no. The second custom field indicates which user(s) are approved to view it, this field can contain multiple values, each in a separate row.

To help debug I'm outputting the WordPress query arguments to a text file while I work on modifying a single function.

When I output the original query from this function this is what I get:

```
Array
(
    [post_type] => property
    [posts_per_page] => 25
    [paged] => 0
    [post_status] => publish
    [meta_query] => Array
        (
            [relation] => AND
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [key] => fave_property_map_address
                            [compare] => EXISTS
                        )

                    [1] => Array
                        (
                            [key] => fave_property_price
                            [value] => Array
                                (
                                    [0] => 100
                                    [1] => 2500
                                )

                            [type] => NUMERIC
                            [compare] => BETWEEN
                        )

                )

        )

    [tax_query] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [taxonomy] => property_status
                    [field] => slug
                    [terms] => available
                )

            [relation] => AND
        )

    [orderby] => date
    [order] => DESC
)
```

This query works perfectly, and returns results almost instantly.

When I modify that query to try to achieve what I'm doing, this is what I get:

```
Array
(
    [post_type] => property
    [posts_per_page] => 25
    [paged] => 0
    [post_status] => publish
    [meta_query] => Array
        (
            [relation] => AND
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [key] => fave_property_map_address
                            [compare] => EXISTS
                        )

                    [1] => Array
                        (
                            [key] => fave_property_price
                            [value] => Array
                                (
                                    [0] => 100
                                    [1] => 2500
                                )

                            [type] => NUMERIC
                            [compare] => BETWEEN
                        )

                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [relation] => OR
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [relation] => AND
                            [0] => Array
                                (
                                    [key] => restricted_access
                                    [value] => 1
                                    [compare] => =
                                )

                            [1] => Array
                                (
                                    [key] => allowed_user
                                    [value] => 1 // User ID of currently logged-in user
                                    [compare] => =
                                )

                        )

                    [1] => Array
                        (
                            [relation] => OR
                            [0] => Array
                                (
                                    [key] => restricted_access
                                    [value] => 0
                                    [compare] => =
                                )

                            [1] => Array
                                (
                                    [key] => restricted_access
                                    [compare] => NOT EXISTS
                                )

                        )

                )

        )

    [tax_query] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [taxonomy] => property_status
                    [field] => slug
                    [terms] => available
                )

            [relation] => AND
        )

    [orderby] => date
    [order] => DESC
)
```

This code doesn't return any results and takes a really long time to actually complete the request according to my browser's developer tools.

The original query is already an "AND" query, and all I'm doing is adding an additional block to that, with some nested conditions.

So in addition to the original query conditions, I'm trying to add the following logic:

- Original Query
  AND
- IF "restricted_access" equals 0, or doesn't exist at all, show the post
  OR
- If "restricted_access" equals "1" and "allowed_user" equals the current user's ID, show the post.

This query takes over a minute to run and doesn't return the expected results. There is a test property that is set as restricted, and the allowed user ID is not mine, but the post still shows.

I think this is a two part problem. Why are the returned results not as expected, and why does this query take so long to run? There are less than 60 properties in the database.

The arguments in my second example above look like they should return the results expected. Any ideas or suggestions?

Comment: `meta_query` is very expensive, especially with multiple clauses, you should make sure you have caching around your queries. Using `meta_query` gets significantly more expensive/slow as the size of the post meta table increases. Also, there is no PHP code in your question and it's unclear how you got that output. `restricted_access` may run much faster if it was a taxonomy,

Comment: @Tom the PHP code is quite long, but I know how to modify it, I'm just not entirely sure the best way to implement this is so I'm not sure what to modify the query to. I can convert the restricted_access custom field to a taxonomy, but I'm still not entirely sure how to query posts that either don't have restricted_access set at all, or that have restricted_access set but the user ID of the current user is listed in a allowed_user field. Because even restricted_access posts have a list of users that should be allowed access.